# How to end body mail in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, email

This is driving me crazy really, I'm sure this problem is addressed many times but I can't find it on this forum or google. So my apologies for making a thread for this.

I don't know how to end the body text.

Much appreciated.

```
    With OutMail
        .To = "" ' Either an email address or a cell value that contains an email address: ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Body = "Geachte heer, mevrouw," & vbNewLine & _
        " " & vbNewLine & _
        "De volgende kasbankopdrachten staan klaar in Kasweb onder rekeningnummer........ Ik verzoek u ze te valideren." & vbNewLine & _
        "Bijgaand ontvangt u het boedeloverzicht, tevens treft u hieronder de berekening van het nog te innen bewindvoerdersalaris en onkosten." & vbNewLine & _
         ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(20) & ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Value & Space(5) & ActiveSheet.Range("B27").Value & vbNewLine & _
         ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value & Space(15) & ActiveSheet.Range("C26").Value & Space(5) & ActiveSheet.Range("B26").Value & vbNewLine & _
         " " & vbNewLine & _
         "Salaris volgens vonnis (incl. 21% BTW)" & Space(14) & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salaris").Cells("42, P").Value & vbNewLine & _
         ""
        .Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value
        .Display  ' Change this to Send if you want to automatically send it without preview
        .Attachments.Add PdfFile  ' Delete this line if you don't want the attachment
    End With
On Error GoTo 0


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Presumably you are writing this VBA in Excel as you refer to ActiveSheet a number of times.  What exactly is the problem you are getting?  The Body element is being set and looks ok?

Comment: I'm getting this error: vba error 5 invalid procedure call or argument
https://gyazo.com/a3f26b6b3615daae6f4fee9d418e72e2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Cells("42, P").Value
```

should be

```
Cells("42", "P").Value
```

You're getting that error because you supplied an *invalid argument* to the `Cells()` method